# Arduino communication with 3 RS485 devices

Tags: serial-port, arduino

This project i am doing for one student final thesis. Its so easy, but i just can not think how to make it. I have RPM counter and RS232 communication on one arduino. RPM counter is working good but communication isn't.
I have 3 RS485 devices > RS485/RS232 converter > RS232/TTL > Arduino.
To receive for ex. second device information i have to send "02READ". Example below, done with Hyperterminal.

```
02READ
02ST,GS,    0.00,kg
002READ
02ST,GS,    0.00,kg
002READ
02ST,GS,    0.00,kg
002READ
02ST,GS,    0.00,kg
0
```

It seems that devices are sending terminating 0, all message is `02ST,GS,    0.00,kg`. Its 19 bytes, right? What is the best solution to ask for 3 devices and then print them to log them on pc? I tried this one, not correct.

```
void READ03(){
      mySerial.println("03READ");
    while (mySerial.available()) { 
     delay(10); 
          if (mySerial.available() >0) {
        char c = mySerial.read();
        readString += c;}
        }
        if (readString.length() == 19) {
      momentas3 = readString;
      readString="";
      }
}
```

I have to go to loop and collect incoming data. But i dont figure out how to do it:( so sad...

All code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MegunoLink.h>
/*
Baltas   +
Raudonas -
Pinout:
============= TCRT1 =============
Juodas       -  GND
Geltons      -  POSSITIVE
Pilkas       -  SIGNAL
============= TCRT2 =============
Rudas        -  GND
Oranzinis    -  POSSITIVE
Zydras       -  SIGNAL
============= TCRT3 =============
Zalias       -  GND
raudonas     -  POSSITIVE
Baltas       -  SIGNAL
*/
//Software serial for 485 communication : Tx = pin 9, Rx = pin 8.
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9,8);
TimePlot MyPlot;
//CONSTANTS:
//Pin number for Vishay Telefunken Opto-reflecting TCRT1000 sensors:
Message MyCSVMessage("Stendas");
#define TCRT1                12     
#define TCRT2                11   
#define TCRT3                10

String readString;
String momentas1;
String momentas2;
String momentas3;
//Number of pulse changes per revolutuion:
long PulsesPerRevolution1 = 78;
long PulsesPerRevolution2 = 192;
long PulsesPerRevolution3 = 82;
long minute = 60;
//VARIABLES:
//Number of pulses counted:
long           PulseCount1=0;       
long           PulseCount2=0;       
long           PulseCount3=0;       
//Calculated rotations per minute:
long        Rpm1       =0;       
long        Rpm2       =0;       
long        Rpm3       =0; 
//Time saved to compare
unsigned long TimeOld    =0;
//Achieved signals saved:
boolean       Status1    =0;       
boolean       Status2    =0;      
boolean       Status3    =0;       
//Signals saved to compare:
boolean       StatusOld1 =0;       
boolean       StatusOld2 =0;       
boolean       StatusOld3 =0;

void setup() {
  //Begin serial communication with BAUD rate 9600bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(57600);

  //Set input pins for TCRT1000:
  pinMode(TCRT1, INPUT);           
  pinMode(TCRT2, INPUT);          
  pinMode(TCRT3, INPUT);          

  MyPlot.SetTitle("Greicio matavimas");
  MyPlot.SetXlabel("Laikas");
  MyPlot.SetYlabel("Greitis");
  MyPlot.SetSeriesProperties("Rpm", Plot::Magenta, Plot::Solid, 2, Plot::Square);
}

void loop() {
  //

  //Read and save TCRT1000 status:
  Status1=digitalRead(TCRT1);      
  Status2=digitalRead(TCRT2);      
  Status3=digitalRead(TCRT3);      
    //Compare current status with the previous one
    //If changed, then increment the counting:
  if (StatusOld1!=Status1){
    StatusOld1=Status1;
    PulseCount1++;
  }
  if (StatusOld2!=Status2){
    StatusOld2=Status2;
    PulseCount2++;
  }  
  if (StatusOld3!=Status3){
    StatusOld3=Status3;
    PulseCount3++;
  }  
  //Compare time if it exceeds 1s:
  if (millis()-TimeOld>=1000){
   //Get data from RS485: 
   READ01();
   READ02();
   READ03();
   //Calculate RPM:
    Rpm1=PulseCount1*minute/PulsesPerRevolution1;
    Rpm2=PulseCount2*minute/PulsesPerRevolution2;
    Rpm3=PulseCount3*minute/PulsesPerRevolution3;
   //Print RPM
    MyCSVMessage.Begin();
    Serial.println(String(Rpm1) + "," + String(momentas1));
    Serial.println(String(Rpm2) + "," + String(momentas2));
    Serial.println(String(Rpm3) + "," + String(momentas3));
    MyCSVMessage.End();
    MyPlot.SendData("Rpm1", Rpm1);
    MyPlot.SendData("Rpm2", Rpm2);
    MyPlot.SendData("Rpm3", Rpm3);

   //reset the counting and time
    TimeOld=millis();
    PulseCount1=0;
    PulseCount2=0;
    PulseCount3=0;    
  }
}
 //Get data from RS485:
void READ01(){
    readString="";
     mySerial.println("01READ");
    while (mySerial.available()) { 
     delay(10); 
          if (mySerial.available() >0) {
        char c = mySerial.read();
        readString += c;}
        }
        if (readString.length() == 19) {
      momentas1 = readString;
      readString="";
      }
}
void READ02(){
    readString="";
     mySerial.println("02READ");
    while (mySerial.available()) { 
     delay(10); 
          if (mySerial.available() >0) {
        char c = mySerial.read();
        readString += c;}
        }
        if (readString.length() == 19) {
      momentas2 = readString;
      readString="";
      }
}
void READ03(){
    readString="";
     mySerial.println("03READ");
    while (mySerial.available()) { 
     delay(10); 
          if (mySerial.available() >0) {
        char c = mySerial.read();
        readString += c;}
        }
        if (readString.length() == 19) {
      momentas3 = readString;
      readString="";
      }
}
```

**Edited** Void:

```
void READ03(){
  while (mySerial.available()){
    mySerial.read();
  }
    mySerial.println("03READ");
    momentas3="";
    delay(20);

    while (mySerial.available()) { 
      char c = mySerial.read();
      momentas3 += c;
     }
    // momentas3 = readString;
    //momentas3.setCharAt(momentas3.length() - 1, '\0');   
}
```

It returns correct data, but in the end there is \0 or \n in the end of string

```
{MESSAGE:Stendas|DATA|
0,01ST,GS,    0.03,kg
 0,02ST,GS,    0.00,kg
 0,03ST,GS,    0.00,kg
```

So i need to delete last char \0 or \n or whatever it is

Comment: It doesn't send 19 characters, it sends 20.  The extra one is a linefeed, '\n', that's how you know you got the entire response without having to count.  Since you don't read it, the next string you read will start with that linefeed character from the previous response.

Comment: Thanks Hans, read till \n helped

Comment: If the `read()` is getting ASCII characters and `\n` and/or NUL termination, then you should write your code to process input strings, and not specify or restrict input by a byte count.  You really do not want to *"delete last char \0 or \n or whatever it is"*, but rather store the input with proper string termination, i.e. a NUL character.  You are receiving canonical input, yet trying to treat it as if it was raw or binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After HARD trying i got help from colleague. Both we found the solution :
Added correct code with comments. Thanks Hans Pasant and Joachim Isaksson for the tips!!!
Correct answer was to read until '\n' (new line) char comes.

```
void READ02(){
  while (mySerial.available()){ // Flush read buffer
    mySerial.read();
  }
    mySerial.println("02READ"); // Send command for second device
    momentas2="";
    delay(20);                  // Wait some time 
    while (mySerial.available()) { //While there is data count it to string
     char c = mySerial.read();
     if (c == '\n'){           //If read char is new line then break.
     break;
      }
      momentas2 += c;       
    }
}
```

And reworking with string to get data i need, to store data between second and third ','.

```
  String between2ndAnd3rd(String myString) {
  int pirmas = myString.indexOf(',');
  int antras = myString.indexOf(',', pirmas+1);
  int trecias = myString.indexOf(',', antras+1);
  int ketvirtas = myString.indexOf(',', trecias+1);

  String newStr = myString.substring(antras+1, trecias);
  return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read fixed size 19 bytes every time, you could do something like this (pardon my rusty arduino skills, you may have to correct me)

```
void READ01() { momentas1 = READ("01READ"); }
void READ02() { momentas2 = READ("02READ"); }
void READ03() { momentas3 = READ("03READ"); }

String READ(String toSend) {

   mySerial.println(toSend);

   String buffer = "";
   int i = 0;
   while (i < 19)
   {
      while (!Serial.available()) { /* Busy wait for next byte */ }
      buffer += Serial.read();
   }
   buffer.Trim();
   return buffer;
}
```

That should fill the corresponding read_buffer with 19 bytes of data from that device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i want to read all incoming bytes and print them, but something goes wrong ;) In the end there is terminating zero \0. I need to delete it, how? See edited post with edited code.